# Dynamically create selectInput ids based on vector length

Tags: r, shiny, apply, lapply

I'm creating a Shiny app which requires certain `divs` to have the same dropdown menus, but I need to give each of the divs a unique id so I can access their input$id.

I've created a function to create the divs based on a vector of values, and when the value in the vector is `ttest` a selectInput should additionally be created.

But how do I make the ids of the select input `ttest_1`, `ttest_2` etc etc if I have multiple `ttest` values in the initial vector?

```
# create a vector with 2 ttest values
test <- c("ttest", "mean", "freq", "ttest")

library(shiny)

# create divs, either just print the name in the vector
# or if the name in the vector is "ttest" then make it a select input
aggBlocks <- function(data, name)
{
  div(style = "
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 12px;
      background-color: #A9A9A9;
      border-radius: 10px;
      color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;
      ",
      if (name == "ttest") {
        # how do I abstractly make the ids ttest_1 and ttest_2 
        # based on the occurances in the vector?
        selectInput(paste0("ttest"), "T-TEST", choices = c("Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3"), selectize = FALSE)
      } else {
        name
      }
  )
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  div(lapply(test, aggBlocks, data = test)),
  verbatimTextOutput("debug")

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$debug <- renderPrint({
    # rather than just print input$ttest
    # need to print ttest_1, ttest_2 etc
    input$ttest
  })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `make.unique` to give unique names to `test` vector which can be used as id's. Then instead of doing an exact match in `aggBlocks` function you can do a partial match with `grepl`.

```
test <- c("ttest", "mean", "freq", "ttest")
library(shiny)

aggBlocks <- function(name)
{
  div(style = "
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 12px;
      background-color: #A9A9A9;
      border-radius: 10px;
      color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;
      ",
      if (grepl('^ttest', name)) {
        selectInput(name, "T-TEST", choices = c("Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3"), 
          selectize = FALSE)
       } else {
         name
       }
     )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(lapply(make.unique(test), aggBlocks)),
  verbatimTextOutput("debug")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$debug <- renderPrint({
   input$ttest
 })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```